# rep() Function Using a Variable for 'times' is Throwing an Error

Tags: r

I have data set (say) `test`:

```
test <- data.frame(x = c(90, 801, 6457, 92727), y = rep("test", 4))
print(test)
      x    y
1    90 test
2   801 test
3  6457 test
4 92727 test
```

I want to create variable `test$z` that mirrors `test$x`, except that `test$z` is always 10 characters long, filling in the gaps with zeros. So the resulting data frame would look like:

```
print(test)
      x    y          z
1    90 test 0000000090
2   801 test 0000000801
3  6457 test 0000006457
4 92727 test 0000092727
```

I thought that the function below would give me the result I'm looking for:

```
test$z <- paste0(as.character(rep(0, 10-nchar(as.character(test$x)))), as.character(test$x))
```

But it kicks back the following error in the `rep` function:

> Error in rep(0, 10 - nchar(as.character(test$x))) :
>         invalid 'times' argument

Any ideas of what I could do differently with the rep function or any other solutions to get `test$z`?

Comment: You can use sprintf.

Comment: or `formatC(test$x, flag = '0', digits = 10, width = 10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem stems from `rep(0, 10-nchar(as.character(test$x)))` where the second argument is a vector which is the `times` argument. Basically, this throws an error:

```
rep(0, c(9, 8, 7, 4))
```

Instead, you should do:

```
rep(c(0,0,0,0), c(9, 8, 7, 4))
```

in which the length of two vectors are the same.

`?rep` states that:

> If times consists of a single integer, the result consists of the whole input repeated this many times. If times is a vector of the same length as x (after replication by each), the result consists of x[1] repeated times[1] times, x[2] repeated times[2] times and so on.

In our example, `x` is `c(0,0,0,0)` and `times` is `c(9, 8, 7, 4)`.

You could do:

```
test$z <- sapply(test$x, function(x) paste0(paste0(rep(0,10-nchar(x)),collapse = ""),x))

#      x    y          z
#1    90 test 0000000090
#2   801 test 0000000801
#3  6457 test 0000006457
#4 92727 test 0000092727
```

Answer (score 3):

In the comments @Roland mentions `sprintf()`, which is a great idea.  And @m0h3n explained the issue with `rep()` in his answer.  Here's an alternative to both.

You could replace `rep()` with the new base function `strrep()`, which will recycle its `x` argument the length of `times`. It seems to work nicely for your case.

```
strrep(0, 10 - nchar(test$x))
# [1] "00000000" "0000000"  "000000"   "00000"
```

So we just paste that onto the front of `test$x` and we're done.  No need for any `as.character` coercion since it's all done internally.

```
paste0(strrep(0, 10 - nchar(test$x)), test$x)
# [1] "0000000090" "0000000801" "0000006457" "0000092727"
```

Note: `strrep()` was introduced in R version 3.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of good answers so far.

For fun, here's an example of a 'quick-and-dirty' way to do it with functions you likely already know.

```
test$z <- substr(paste0('0000000000', as.character(test$x)),
                 nchar(test$x),
                 10+nchar(test$x))
```

Just paste more zeroes than you'll need *(e.g., 10)* to each entry, and substring.

P.S. You could replace the string of zeroes in the above code with a string of length *n* by instead writing:

```
paste0(rep(0, n), collapse='')
```